# Unable to solve transportation optimization using genalg in R

Tags: r

I was trying to solve the below transportation problem using `lpsolve` and `genalg` in R. I am facing some problems using `genalg`.

```
            Boston  New York    Supply
---------------------------------------  
Detroit     30      20          200  
Pittsburgh  40      10          100
---------------------------------------  
Demand      150     150
```

Here is the link to the problem statement in case the above problem is not clear.
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/ormpug/66107/HTML/default/viewer.htm#ormpug_optmodel_sect005.htm

Code using `genalg`:

```
    library(genalg)  
    dataset <- data.frame(arc = c("det_bos", "det_new", "pit_bos", 
   "pit_new"), cost = c(30, 20, 40, 10), supply_1 = c(1,1,0,0),
    supply_2 = c(0,0,1,1),demand_1 = c(1,0,1,0),demand_2 = c(0,1,0,1))

 supply_1_limit <- 200  
 supply_2_limit <- 100  
 demand_1_limit <- 150  
 demand_2_limit <- 150

evalFunc <- function(arc=c()) {  
current_solution_cost <- arc%*%dataset$cost  
current_solution_supply_1 <- arc%*%dataset$supply_1  
current_solution_supply_2 <- arc%*%dataset$supply_2  
current_solution_demand_1 <- arc%*%dataset$demand_1  
current_solution_demand_2 <- arc%*%dataset$demand_2

if (current_solution_supply_1 < supply_1_limit | 
    current_solution_supply_2 < supply_2_limit | 
    current_solution_demand_1 > demand_1_limit | 
    current_solution_demand_2 > demand_2_limit)    
    return(0) else return(current_solution_cost)}

 GAmodel <- rbga(stringMin=c(0,0,0,0), 
 stringMax=c(150,150,150,150),       
 suggestions=NULL,popSize=200, 
 iters=100, mutationChance=0.10,elitism=T,
 monitorFunc=NULL,evalFunc=evalFunc,showSettings=FALSE, verbose=FALSE)

 cat(summary.rbga(GAmodel))
```

When I put the best solution derived from the model above it doesn't come with the correct figures. I have tried changing the number of iterations but it didn't help.

```
solution =c(37.3445626697503, 108.823138475418, 124.833289347589, 1.39844713266939)  
sum(solution)  
total_cost = solution%*%dataset$cost  
print(total_cost)
```

The answer should be

```
Total Cost = 6500 , Units Shipped = 300  as ( 150 , 50, 0 , 100)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you are using lpSolve.  Did you know that lpSolve has a dedicated interface for transportation problems? Load lpSolve and look at `? lp.transport`.

Here is the implementation for your example problem:

```
library(lpSolve)
cost.mat  <- matrix(c(30,20,40,10), nrow=2,byrow=TRUE)
row.signs <- c("=","=")
col.signs <- c("=","=")
col.rhs <- c(150,150)
row.rhs <- c(200,100)
sol<-lp.transport (cost.mat, direction="min", row.signs, row.rhs, 
            col.signs, col.rhs, presolve=0,  compute.sens=0, integers = 1:4 )
```

And the solution is:

```
> sol$solution
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  150   50
[2,]    0  100
```

which matches the SAS result.

Comment: Thank you for the response. We have already solved that problem using lpsolve. Now we are trying to solve it using metaheuristics and thereby trying the approach of genalg. It will be helpful if it can be solved using genalg.